# Ready Emacs setup for C

Tags: c, emacs, ide

I've made topic for vim already [Ready VIM setup for C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12866375/342843) and I'd like also get something similar to [spf13-vim](http://vim.spf13.com), but for emacs

Comment: Why are you speaking about Vim and Emacs together? They are completely unrelated tools, the tasks that do are completely different. Vim is a text editor, Emacs is a kitchen sink.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Google search for "vim plugins" prodices  2,090,000 results.  Vim might have started out as just a pipe for text, but the kitchen sink has been built around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at [Emacs Prelude](http://batsov.com/prelude/).

Prelude is an enhanced Emacs 24.x configuration that features a lot of sensible defaults, additional 3rd party packages and powerful setups for most popular programming languages. It's very modular and has the nice ability to auto-install some packages on demand - for instance the first time you open a Clojure source file Prelude will automatically install support for Clojure programming.

There are many other preconfigured Emacs distributions as well - Emacs Starter Kit, Emacs Live, etc...

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included some form of description of Emacs Prelude.

Comment: Fair enough - I extended the answer a bit.

Comment: That's a nice addition. You might also want to mention that it's only for Emacs 24.x.